# Update toolbar according listview

Tags: android, listview, toolbar

I am developing an android app. I need to update toolbar according to  the listview.
The effect looks like this:
[image]
[image]

I tried 2 solutions:

**Solution 1:** Create 2 toolbar ( toolbar1 and toolbar2). When the listview scrolls up: hides toolbar1 and shows toolbar2 , when the listview scrolls down: shows toolbar1 and hides toolbar2.

**Solution 2:** Create menu Item that contains all items then inflating to the menu. When the listview scrolls up: setVisible for some item is true and another is false.

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.home_menu, menu);
```

But both of solutions don't look likes correctly.

Do you have any idea or any suggestion ?

Comment: Are you looking for http://www.feelzdroid.com/2015/08/collapsing-toolbars-android-example.html ? https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/CollapsingToolbarLayout.html

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. But CollapsingToolbar doesn't work in this situation.

Comment: have the items in toolbar make it invisible and visible based on user scrolling. No need for two toolbars.

Comment: @Raghumandan: How about the effect when makes the items visible and invisible

Comment: not sure what kind of effect your looking for. Its not clear to me. Anyway this is the best i can think of for now

Comment: Thank you all. I found ViewFlipper, it resolves my problem.